# Play Framework - Passing Application Arguments via Docker Container

Tags: docker, playframework, sbt

Before dockerizing my play web application, I was able to do the following when running:

```
Joes-Macbook:project-1 joe$ sbt -Dconfig.env=dev run
```

Where I can use one of the following of either dev, qa, prod to the config.env argument and my application will run using the corresponding application.dev.conf or application.qa.conf accordingly.

Now I have my application as a docker container which means that I need a way to inject my configuration file. How could I do it?

One way what I'm thinking is to have a shell script and use that as the Entrypoint. But not sure how this might work? Any suggestions?

So when I do

> sbt docker:publishLocal

I get the following Dockerfile produced

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java:8_server-jre_unlimited
MAINTAINER Joesan <myemail@email.com>
WORKDIR /opt/docker
ADD opt /opt
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon:daemon", "."]
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "bin/project-1", "-Denv=$configEnv"]
CMD []
ENV configEnv default
```

I could not get the $configEnv resolved in my Scala application. This is how I run the produced docker image:

```
docker run -e "configEnv=crap" --rm --name play-8080 -p 8080:9000 joesan/project-1:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set en [environment variable when you use `docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables) (or in [`docker compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/))

```
docker run -e "deep=purple" ...
```

That means your Dockerfile can declare that [same variable as `ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env), and be used by your default `CMD`.

```
ENV configEnv
CMD sbt -Dconfig.env=${configEnv} run
```

---

Though, the OP is working with [`sbt-native-packager`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html), which [generates a Dockerfile](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/a50782ed0a9bc9ccf41a6dbb1a25bce6e3c43ace/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/docker/dockerfile.scala).
[Issue 861](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/861) shows how to add commands to the generated Dockefile:

```
dockerCommands ++= Seq (
      // setting the run script executable
      ExecCmd("RUN", "chmod", "u+x", s"${(defaultLinuxInstallLocation in Docker).value}/bin/${executableScriptName.value}")
    )
```

That means you can declare ENV that way.

And [issue 927](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/927) shows how to override the default `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
dockerEntrypoint := Seq("bin/my-app", "-Dconfig.resource=application-prod.conf")
```

Combining the two should allow to implement the solution I proposed above.

---

Actually, [after discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148422/discussion-between-sparkr-and-vonc), overriding is no good, because the generated `Dcokerfile` would have `ENTRYPOINT` *followed* by the `ENV` declaration, which is not good.

Only by *adding* both `ENV` and `ENTRYPOINT`, one can generate the correct `Dockerfile`, as illustrated by the [OP sparkr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3102968/sparkr) below.

Comment: That might work, but I use the sbt native packager, which means that I do not have control of the docker file that is being produced as the Dockerfile is generated when I build the project!

Comment: @sparkr You can easily make your own image based on that generated image, no?

Comment: I want to perhaps avoid that! What I just figured out is that there is a dockerEntryPoint that I could configure: http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#configuration

Comment: With this dockerEntryPoint, I can write a custom script that can then take this parameter!

Comment: Yes, I had a look at that and seems to be the way to go!

Comment: Can you please take a look at the edited post? I could not get this to work!

Comment: @sparkr You have the `ENV configEnv` declaration I mention in my answer, and which is presented in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env at the wrong place: it must be declared first, then used.

Comment: Hmmm... I do not know why it is declared after! Is it a generated file from the sbt native packager

Comment: @sparkr My point is: you need to generate the ENV line *before* the ENTRYPOINT line. And with https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/861, I know you can add lines: add 2 lines: one for ENV, one for ENTRYPOINT (again)

Comment: Let me give that a try!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148422/discussion-between-sparkr-and-vonc).

Answer (score 2):

So with the help from VonC, and few changes to my build.sbt, I made it to work:

This is what I have in my build.sbt:

```
dockerCommands ++= Seq(
  Cmd("ENV", "configEnv", "default"), // This will be overridden when running!
  // This is the entrypoint where we can run the application against different environments
  ExecCmd("ENTRYPOINT", "sh", "-c", "bin/" + s"${executableScriptName.value}" + " -Denv=$configEnv")
)
```

So when I run my docker command:

```
docker run -e "configEnv=test" --rm --name play-8080 -p 8080:9000 joesan/project-1:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The appropriate application.test.conf gets picked up, loaded and my play application runs against it!

Comment: Well done! +1. Generating ENTRYPOINT (nistead of just overriding it) was key.

Comment: Your clue did help me in sorting this out!

Comment: I have edited my answer to point out that overriding `ENTRYPOINT` was not a good option in this case.